# JSF h:messages render global message is not rerendered

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-7

I'm trying to display global error messages which are sent from EJB with:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                            "Please select a path first", "title"));
```

right now the JSF has the following code:

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true"/>
```

The above however doesn't work because the JSF page is not rerendered.
Notice I am able to make the above work using primefaces, if I substitute the JSF code with the following:

```
<p:messages globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

However I don't want to use primefaces and I want a pure JSF solution.
Notice also I don't want the h:messages to be inside a form as there's no button to click, I want the h:messages to be auto updated from the EJB but without using primefaces.

Comment: I am "a" famous Sarah.. but not the one you probably meant :P

Comment: Just in case, you can also use a `<x:commandButton>` with `AJAX` to update a `<x:message>` which does not contain `autoupdate="true"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to render the `<h:messages />` else it wont show.
You can achive this by rendering the message from the managedbean.

```
<h:messages id="globalMessage" />
```

And in your managedBean you place a code to render the messages after  your

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "Please select a path first", "title"));

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds()
.add("globalMessage");
```

But be sure you have the correct Id to be rendered.